# In Flow, what does Missing an annotation on implicit `this` parameter of function. [missing-this-annot] mean?

Tags: flowtype

I have a Javascript file that looks like this:

```
// @flow
/**
 * My database module.
 *
 * Interact with the database.
 */
'use strict';

module.exports = {

  /** Mockable wrapper around mongoose. */
  mongoose: function() /*:: : Object */ {
    // $FlowExpectedError
    return require('mongoose');
  },

  /** Mockable wrapper around env. */
  env: function() /*:: : Object */ {
    // $FlowExpectedError
    return require('./env.js');
  },

  /** Initialize the connection to Mongoose. */
  init: function(
    callbackOK /*:: : () => number */,
    callbackInitError /*:: : (x: string) => null */,
    callbackError /*:: : (x: string) => null */) {

    try {
      // See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html.
      this.mongoose().connect(this.uri(), {}).then(
        () => callbackOK(),
        err => callbackInitError(err),
      );
      this.mongoose().connection.on('error',
        err => callbackError(err),
      );
    }
    catch (err) {
      callbackInitError(err);
    }
  },

  /** Get the connection URI for the Mongoose database. */
  uri: function() /*:: : string */ {
    const user = String(this.env().required('MONGO_USER'));
    const pass = String(this.env().required('MONGO_PASS'));
    const host = String(this.env().required('MONGO_HOST'));
    const port = String(this.env().required('MONGO_PORT'));
    const db = String(this.env().required('MONGO_DB'));

    return 'mongodb://' + user + ':' + pass + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + db + '?authSource=admin';
  },
};
```

When I check it with [Flow](https://flow.org), it gives me this error:

```
Missing an annotation on implicit `this` parameter of function. [missing-this-annot]

                       v
   24|   init: function(
   25|     callbackOK /*:: : () => number */,
   26|     callbackInitError /*:: : (x: string) => null */,
   27|     callbackError /*:: : (x: string) => null */) {
           -------------------------------------------^
```

How would I modify this code to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

### Reason

According to https://medium.com/flow-type/sound-typing-for-this-in-flow-d62db2af969e, you have to explicitly type the `This` parameter.

Let's just say that Flow was not producing any error here. Then Flow could not prevent you to do this:

```
const foo = module.exports.uri;
foo();
```

But this will throw at runtime as global `this` doesn't have an `env` function.

### Solution 1

You could define a type for your module:

```
type MyModule = {
  mongoose:  () => Object,
  env: () => Object,
  init: 
    (callbackOK : () => number,
    callbackInitError: (x: string) => null,
    callbackError: (x: string) => null) => void,

  uri: () => string
}
```

Then in the functions where you call `this`, you would have to add a special `this` annotation:

```
  uri: function(this: MyModule) {
```

This shouldn't change the function signature as long as you have have a recent version of Babel (at least  7.13.0 according to the article above).

[Flow try link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQwBULGhaAsgT1ACYCGALkQEZEDOApqALawECu0NAdBupqAJIB2JGgCciAYxKh4ASxIALUPLrEylWp0zBEAcma1QVEsOkTtAbkSISuAA5082JqxoBeUAG8MDWPwDmsWFoALlBQAAoASlAXAD5QAHlyACsaCQAaLxp+ADcQyOi4xJT0r1QsAVlpImhpAC86JVAxH35UkmkfRVgcH39Ajk0vaX5ZEK9QsLFq6EoxAGt4gGlQPKjY0H5menIRDNDQqegZ8TmKkgBRYWFYYTyADxDDYz81uM2jvf3D4-nL69vwg8DEZhr5XhtWNBwdlYNICBkvMxjKsCsDnr5EABfSyMFhsdg0O42G4kKjRDyWUKMPwBYKgSDMfgSDr8fKoIIhEJFNqaCn7UAgUAAEgAYnB4OciW0aAQ-jdxqBhDQSEj+IqaABHZjSJVhbTUvq0bQRCyhTEI0JlHrzChsKSiGx2YSgIjXRkEUBZbLsQahL0hBlM9o+NkoDkrBLJHkoMCefmC0XiyV2CQyuXCBVKlXCNVKrU6mh69jAL3sJJUY2m0DmrylNB8Ebtap1BpyOjNfitZmdEjdRw0-o+mNDRsBxnd1nyaRUEIOJxsT4HaazBbLdmc8LgzbbESaRdNZcnM7pgVhjdhIFPUFbyF7hXfFcn9cRi+PEEvVHvaCaKKeBVGfA435AUwAAZRoOg5BIEgbBnEADVpGhy3YZp6GAAhYDEKhgA7Ltg34Kh2Cg+hoA0YCp0IhD+kiFCWjaMIKPYJFpEiNIPExCJ2CUVkFX5fJ1gfE4llY3j9hEZ0BMPeZjyuG4wnEiJ91CE1RMYqjaBo3C2hZdgQ20cSbm0JSxKuVFBN+WThHkq5FNElT+WxfkphIMQFGs4Rf1E8zTkbdN3Ps-ZHOrC1TywABxZVFDbJo6InUAAFUACVeHpG4ovsXpEMIUgKGoAZh1CZixyDFkGLkadZ1wRw8RoTynJ8QxQD0Xc3FA99fDK6cCRyGi821JUCD1bB4gAOTC+IAH14tA85EuNAKDgayQbGoMlWvazrCK9XrNX6mUhtG8aJoABQAQVA0D5qrRaCMkORAkkdb0U27rsh2-MBoOsbJoACXiUCABUrvvJbQGJYRHtANrnsY7bOL6gtBu0YbvpO+JEqBiIFpi27CHIclodBF64fYBHPuRw7JoAEQAIWBzNlVVUB9UyghyCCEBtFAABqJraGdXntCCLneZWqgyUF8ARdAe7GsF4WebBklFe0YBpbZlWAH4iGYeRQNgJExFcIgCHoYZzC8GtMTMIA)

### Solution 2

You might not like defining the types into two different places. Then why not get rid of `this` altogether?

Declare each function at the top level, e.g.

```
function uri() /*:: : string */ {
    const user = String(env().required('MONGO_USER'));
    ...
}
```

And then export them:

```
module.exports = {
  mongoose, 
  env,
  init,
  uri,
}
```

[Flow try link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQwBULGhaAsgT1ACYCGALkQEZEDOApqALawECu0NAdBupqAJIB2JGgCciAYxKh4ASxIALUPLrEylWp0zBEAcma1QVEsOkTtAbkQZQqLNlhiA1hTZTRABzcjQRYbGb8CBlh+AHNYWHVNREh-CWlgoNDw2gAKAEprFAAuLNBcgHlyACsaCU1QAG8rUGswABIAMTh4AFEAD08JGgIW4V9hatBhGhJmYX4hmgBHZmlhlO1GJIiabTSLGoBfSxqbHHsnchd4d09hb19-QJp+ADd2KJj+OISb2-TMnLzQQpKylDAVRqu3qTQQ7U6Qh6fVgA2Bk1G40mMzmNAW7GAb3YRSoaw2oG2Vj2Alk0iI0GkAC86EpQGJgvxSiR4hMSLB9stIgDorFmQlpPxZClBmJydBKI58gBpT65XIfAC8AD5QPxmPRyF4AQAaEViiUOEkkXr9WXfFJtXKGYyhDLK1WsaCaXXw0XQcXiBwm2Fm+WWgxGAUhO0qtXuzQZKqDIz4IHw2qgADKNDochIJDcVCyICWYRWOPY9PowAI9iowHp-EZL34VHYafo0A08dzyTRaULDKZKTG0nS2sqmw7Sn4wvjwMVKrdHslUv7g3hInO9unBqN3uEKSXaRd8fWC8SedSHcr1b5-HYwQWS9h2l346XoBX+s9G63fR3B-38O2rtIYgUd9hEjA9V09dcYU3bd8S2KxCV2NBQAAcRGRQ5DoU8mRZUAAFUACVeFASAfVpOxOWUUgKGoDhHl5bDew+VAvitQNQnKOMakrQxQD0LwFSTViQi3O50nYYYUWGAgFmwfIADkkPyAB9HDExaPC1m-YEuMkNxqCoJ8BJtIS3lE8TZkk6S5IUxSAAUAEFE0TDSYLpYJuLkCJJH4xNBOE94OzM1EpO0GT5KUgAJfJEwAFWckU3J02EvMMoM-NM6ZzO6Sywts-I8NitJNM4hLCHIAyfKMtKAoyoLsusgARAAhOLBmGREJkWYIwgIchs2AbRQAAah42hzmG7QsgG4bdKofTxvAKbQA87jxsmobQDcJL1u0fr1p67aAH4iGYeREz8YQxBoBUiAIegBXMRBCUYFg2HYGgOiS-T+LjVsVgHKw3l3AVZF3XtdU2IA)